# composed for comprehension in scala

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I have a list of tasks in a for-comprehension:

```
def main = {
    List("en", "es", "de").foreach(c => execAll(c))
} 

def execAll(country: String): Future[Unit] = {
   for {
      _ <- repo.exec1(country)
      _ <- repo.exec2(country)
      _ <- repo.exec3(country)
      _ <- repo.exec4(country)
      _ <- repo.exec5(country)
   } yield ()
}
```

The problem now is because I need to execute functions `exec4` and `exec5` only for "en" and "es" countries.
I tried to add the functions in a list of futures by condition (`if country == "en"` don't add it)

```
val all = for {
      _ <- repo.exec1(country)
      _ <- repo.exec2(country)
      _ <- repo.exec3(country)
} yield ()

val enOrEsOnly = for {
      _ <- repo.exec4(country)
      _ <- repo.exec5(country)
} yield ()

country match {
    case "de" => all
    case other => all + enOrEsOnly // invalid code
}
```

Can find a solution using `for-comprehension` here? Or can just use a list of futures here? I don't need their results. thanks

Or I can just use an `if` to solve it:

```
if (country != "de") {
   repo.exec4(country)
   repo.exec5(country)
}
```

Comment: This code ```all + enOrEsOnly``` can be replaced by flatMap: ```all.flatMap(_ => enOrEsOnly)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replace `execAll` by:

```
def execAll(country: String): Future[Unit] = {
   for {
      _ <- repo.exec1(country)
      _ <- repo.exec2(country)
      _ <- repo.exec3(country)
      if country != "de"
      _ <- repo.exec4(country)
      _ <- repo.exec5(country)
   } yield ()
}
```

Comment: Note that in this case, the `Future` will be completed with a failure. This means that if the result of this function is then composed using `map` and `flatMap` it will shortcircuit.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather add an extra layer over `repo` that has the validations, that way your code will be the same, and in that extra layer you would do something like this:

```scala
final class Domain(repo: Repository) {
  def exec4(country: String): Future[Unit] =
    country match {
      case "en" | "es" => repo.exec4(country)
      case _ => Future.unit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. I choosed @esse's solution for simplicity, but upvoted your answer for good explanation. Also, saw your comment on his post and should be taken in consideration.